# Windows Service DLL Replace

Tags: c#, windows, service

If I have a DLL that's been updated within a function, and I just need to update it (the DLL) for a Windows Service - will it work by me, just copying the DLL and restarting the service?
Or do I have to have to follow the InstallUtil process?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simply replacing the dll and restarting should work. However, you might need to stop the service first before replacing, because the dll is 'in use by another process'.