# C# Windows Service: Updating only a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, service, windows-services, .net-3.5

I have a Windows Service which depends on one DLL among others. I have changed a method of one DLL, only its content, not the signature.

For example, old method in DLL is:

```
public void CalculateTaxes()
{
   // Old content
}
```

and the new method is:

```
public void CalculateTaxes()
{
   // New content
}
```

Note that signature is the same, I am only changing the content.

So my question is: Stopping service, then replacing only the DLL affected and finally starting service is enough to changes take effect or Do I need to replace the entire windows service? In my case only this DLL is affected, the rest of DLLs and Windows service are the same (no changes).

I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784854/windows-service-dll-replace) but as answer has not been accepted and according to the comment done to this answer, I am not sure if changing only DLL affected is enough.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Why don't you try and find out.

Comment: Only DLL replacement is fine.

Comment: I personally had these situations on one of the projects, after we changed .dll we had IIS reset and it worked like a charm ... but can't guarantee it will be same case, you never know what can go wrong

Comment: Nikhil is right. You could throw together a barebones test and find out for yourself in the time it took to pose the question on SO.

Comment: As long as your dll is not strongly signed - it should be fine and you really don't need to recompile your exe with new dll

Comment: No change in the method signature so you don't have to worry about a MissingMethodException.  You do have to worry about changing the [AssemblyVersion], the program still looks for the original version and is not going to be happy when a new one unless it is force to with a config file.  Not changing the version is not a great idea, at least change the [AssemblyFileVersion].  Micro-managing this is, well, blah.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind the answer depends on how the dll is referenced in the service. If it is referenced to a specific version replacing the dll would resolve in a assemlby not found exception. If the version is not specific it depends only on the name of the assembly and the method, so replacement should work.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022134/how-exactly-does-the-specific-version-property-of-an-assembly-reference-work-i) for more informations on "Specific Version".